# How to execute python script on a server with an url call or webhook

Tags: python, php, selenium, cgi, shell-exec

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBYqa.png)i need to execute a python script on my server by calling it from the server url or from a webhook, like http://myserver.net/myscript.py but i can't figure out how, i'm fairly new to this. The script uses selenium and open a chrome window and get to google homepage. I tried with a php file, using shell_exec command but it fails at opening the chrome window, probably because the script is executed by the apache profile. The script runs fine when called in bash with my profile. I heard about CGI to get ride of php but i don't know this at all. Any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: *... shell_exec command but it fails*, whats the error ?

Comment: How should a process handled by a system service open a window in a specific user session? That won't work, even if you could get that to work it would be a horrible hack. CGI (or fastcgi these days) is not "to get rid of php", it is an alternative execution environment which can execute arbitrary implementations, executable themselves or on some scripting language like php or python. There also used to be a python module for the apache http server, the other way 'round, haven't seen it for a while though...

Comment: To address your specific issue: so what does your http server's error log file say what the specific issue is? Or the logfile of the fastcgi server, if that is what you use?

Comment: I explained it wrong, the shell_exec() does not fails. The script execution fails. The error i get seems to be about the  chromedriver as the command is executed by the apache user (if i understood well with the shell_exec() doc), i guess it can't open a chrome instance. I tried to open chrome from bash with the apache user and got also an error ("Trace/Breakpoint trap (core dump)"). I'll try to post the error i get with the script execution.

Comment: Is it possible to execute the command with shell_exec() but with my user account and not www-data?

Answer (score 0):

As per your error_log Chrome is not properly closed and says "Chrome has crashed".
To execute python file and selenium chromedriver.exe the following things are properly checked:

1. Go to **Task manger** and stop running **chromedriver.exe** (on Windows)
2. Close all running Google Chrome application.
3. Now hit your URL `localhost/index.php?token=a`

> Note: You won't see selenium chromedrive window and google chrome window, but these are running as background process after you execute python by PHP `shell_exec()` command.